# Iteration over ConsumerIterator object seems to be never ending loop

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I try to implement a Java consumer client for Apache Kafka in version 0.8.2.1. I know that new version of Java Consumer API will be available in new version of Apache Kafka, but for now I have to implement consumer client in the current version.

So I have done it, but I have problem with checking count of received messages. The problem seems to be in iteration over the ConsumerIterator object to get the message and  its id. The iteration seem to be be never ending loop. Look at the following code:

```
public class TestKafkaConsumer extends Thread{

private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestKafkaConsumer.class);
private Properties appProperties;
private String topic;
private ZookeeperConsumerConnector consumer;

public TestKafkaConsumer() throws Exception {
    topic = "topic";
    consumer = (ZookeeperConsumerConnector) Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(createConsumerConfig());
}

public static void main( String[] args ){
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    try {
        TestKafkaConsumer testConsumer = new TestKafkaConsumer();
        testConsumer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error create consumer ", e);
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    logger.info("Consumer thread - start");
    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1));
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = (Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>>) consumer
            .createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = consumerMap.get(topic).get(0);
    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
    //logger.info("Count of consumed messages: " + it.length());
    long msgCount = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
            MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> messageAndMetadata  = it.next();
            logger.info("Key: " + new String(messageAndMetadata.key()));
            logger.info("Message: " + new String(messageAndMetadata.message()));
            msgCount++;
        }
    logger.info("Summary count of consumed messages: " + msgCount); 
}

private ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig() throws Exception{
    logger.info("createConsumerConfig - start");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
    props.put("group.id","testGrp");
    props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "400");
    props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "10000");
    logger.info("createConsumerConfig - finish");
    return new ConsumerConfig(props);                
}

}
```

The problem is that the log entry with the count of consumed messages does not appear in log file, so I suppose that iteration never ends. I have tested that all messages are read. So all records are iterated but program does not leave a loop. Additionally I've noticed, when I try to get length of **ConsumerIterator** (or size) before starting a loop (**uncomment appriopriate line**) the program seems to stop in this place and the loop doesn't even start - there is no entry about read records in log file.

Where is the problem - in class ConsumerIterator? Maybe I've done something wrong. I would be grateful if someone met such problem and could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for ConsumerIterator, http://apache.mirrorcatalogs.com/kafka/0.8.2-beta/scala-doc/index.html#kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator, states "An iterator that **blocks until a value can be read from the supplied queue**."

Could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes, it is the issue. When I shutdown a thread and consumer after some time, I get the info abou summary consumed messages. Thanks a lot.